# NFSD client IP testing state ID with incorrect client ID

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, mount, nfs

I've been seeing these messages in my local NFS server logs:

```
NFSD client 192.168.0.126 testing state ID with incorrect client ID
```

Googling for this doesn't give much:

- This ticket seems to think it's related, but nobody comes to a conclusion: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1785788
- Here's the source code for Ubuntu 20.04(kernel 5.4) where this message is printed: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.4/fs/nfsd/nfs4state.c#L5452-L5468

From what I understand, this means that the NFS server is expecting an ID from the client but the client has a different ID, is that correct?

But most of all: I'd like to find out what is causing this. How can I investigate this?

I'm reading that extra logs from NFS isn't really a thing and I have to use a tool called `rpcdebug`? Is that right?

Or maybe someone knows very specifically what causes this exact message and can enlighten the issue.

What I absolutely want to avoid is any command that would result in the NFS server crashing.